# Rails Routes - Limiting the available formats for a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a series of resources that I want only available if accessed via the JS format.  Rails' route resources gives me the formats plus the standard HTML.  Is there a way to specify that only the JS format routes be created?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Can you accept my answer below, its the correct one, the current selected answer is wrong and confusing the community.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You just add constraints about format :

```
resources :photos, :constraints => {:format => /(js|json)/}
```

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, that still allows me to access /photos as :html.  I get the missing template message, when I'd expect a missing route exception.  Thoughts?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `/(js|json)/`?

Comment: Yeah, I caught that and changed it.  Still doesn't work for me.  I have     resources :members, :controller => 'homes/members', :constraints => {:format => /js/}

Comment: this will not limit requests to those formats, see my answer below for the correct implementation

Answer (score 65):

You must wrap those routes in a scope.  Constraints unfortunately don't work as expected in this case.

This is an example of such a block...

```
scope :format => true, :constraints => { :format => 'json' } do
  get '/bar' => "bar#index_with_json"
end
```

More information can be found here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5548

Comment: If you're using `resources`, you don't need a scope block, just add the `:format => true` and `:constraints => ...` directly to the `resources` call.

Comment: This worked in my case for resourcefull route. `resources :photos, format: true, constraints: 'json'`

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that this requires the url to have the file extension on it

Comment: @steve.hanson to avoid the format requirement in the URL, use a lambda for constraint: `get :foo, constraints: lambda { |req| req.format == :json }`.

Comment: The problem is when I wrap the route in a scope block, other code in my rails fails because the link_to command cant  find this wrapped route anymore

Comment: Reiterating the comment by @RocketR above, **this solution does not work**, and [it's mentioned in the rails routing documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). (See the callout starting "There is an exception for the format constraint...") You need to use a lambda for a route format constraint, not a plain hash: `constraints: lambda { |req| req.format == :json }`, or equivalently, `constraints: ->(req) { req.format == :json }`

Answer (score 8):

None of the above solutions worked for me. I ended up going with this solution:

```
post "/test/suggestions", to: "test#suggestions", :constraints => -> (req) { req.xhr? }
```

Found on https://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/routing-only-ajax-requests-in-ror/#comment-375

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
# routes.rb

class OnlyAjaxRequest
  def matches?(request)
    request.xhr?
  end
end

post "/test/suggestions", to: "test#suggestions", :constraints => OnlyAjaxRequest.new
```

it doesn't get to the controller at all. Taken from [railsadventures](http://railsadventures.wordpress.com/2012/10/07/routing-only-ajax-requests-in-ror/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need not only one or another than `json` (cant use `#xhr?`) I offer to you option below

`resource :offers, only: :show, format: true, constraints: { format: 'pdf' }`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

That's how I do it:

```
class OnlyAjaxRequest  
    def matches?(request)
      request.xhr? and request.format.to_s.match(/(js|json|javascript)/).present?
    end
  end

match 'remote_login', to: 'remote_content#remote_login', via: [:get], :constraints => OnlyAjaxRequest.new
```

If you only care about the format, leave just the request.format part

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `before_filter` that raises a routing error unless the request format is `MIME::JS`.

app/controllers/application_controller.rb:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :check_js

  private
    def check_js
      raise RoutingError.new('expected application/json') unless request.format == MIME::JS
    end
end
```

Apply this filter more surgically with `:only`, `:except`, and `:skip_before_filter` as covered in the rails [Action Controller Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters)

Comment: I've used a similar approach to handle this kind of problem https://github.com/marcusg/force_format