# rails4 // ActionController::UnknownFormat

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, request, format

Some bots or other external requests cause an `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error when redirecting

Is there a catch-all method to add somewhere in application_controller to handle those errors ?

A config spec to add a default method in request (if none specified) ?

Below an example of trace :

```
An ActionController::UnknownFormat occurred in main#index:

  ActionController::UnknownFormat
  app/controllers/main_controller.rb:17:in `index'


-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

  * URL        : http://ownedurl.com/
  * HTTP Method: GET
  * IP address : 82.xxx.xxx.xxx
  * Parameters : {"controller"=>"main", "action"=>"index"}
  * Timestamp  : 2015-06-07 20:54:32 +0200
  * Server : servername
  * Rails root : /var/www/ownedurl.com/releases/208
  * Process: 29726
```

A get request would obviously work; yet it makes it occurs.

Experiences on this one appreciated
thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will handle a request without format :

```
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownFormat, with: :raise_not_found
def raise_not_found
    render(text: 'Not Found', status: 404)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply the [`:format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) to your routes itself to tell it what are the formats are valid and which are not.

Read some [discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/upWLY6WeD1U) on this and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679200/rails-routes-limiting-the-available-formats-for-a-resource).

Comment: good point. main#index is actually the root of the app. what's the syntax to specify the format in it ?

Comment: @Ben did you check ?/

Comment: I'll check tomorrow. Added `root :to => 'main#index', :defaults => { :format => 'html' }`. Thing is, I don't know how to address a request without format with curl or other similar tool